# Cmake Openssl not found

Tags: cmake, openssl, cross-compiling

Want to cross-compile a C application that uses Azure IoT SDK, which unfortunately requires Cmake. Cmake refuses to build my toolchain because it claims that it cannot find Openssl that I've compiled for my target architecture.

I've tried adding `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` to the folder it's in.

```
SET(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /path/to/openssl)
```

I continually get the error:

```
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_LIBRARIES) (found
  version "1.0.2g")
```

I also tried setting system variables to these folder as the error suggests, but it seemingly ignores them and prompts the same error. I've tried adding it to the same folder as my C compiler also to no avail.

I've run out of things to try and this point and I do not understand why it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems, that **root directory** of your OpenSSL installation is `/path/to/openssl`. Why do you attempt to set *OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR* variable to `/path/to/openssl/lib` instead? Also, *OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR* variable is set by the `find_package(OpenSSL)` call, do not set this variable manually.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ah, oops. That's a typo. Did not know about the include, but the error is the same.

Comment: Actually, CMake finds *part* of OpenSSL library: there is no `INCLUDE_DIR` in the "missing" list, and there is version (`1.0.2g`). Is this version corresponds to your OpenSSL installation? In file `CMakeCache.txt`, located in the build directory, find (via `grep` or so) entries contained `OPENSSL`, and among them find ones contained `LIBRARY`. Which entries have `NOTFOUND` value?

Comment: It is, yes. `OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND` and 
`OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND`

Comment: Hm, `OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY` variable corresponds to `libcrypto` library, `OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY` corresponds to `libssl` one. Do you have these libraries under `lib/` subdirectory of your OpenSSL installation? As for cross-compiling... Your OpenSSL installation is for **target** platform (Azure IoT SDK), doesn't it? Also, entry `OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR` in `CMakeCache.txt` refers to your OpenSSL installation, doesn't it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yeah, they're in the `lib/`. Yes. The `OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DUR` is the correct path `openssl/include`.

Comment: Weird. The last attempt. Does your toolchain set `CMAKE_SYSROOT` variable? If so, path hints should normally come as **relative** to sysroot.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it does, but using a relative path gives the same error.

Comment: And what value of toolchain variables, started with `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER`, `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY`, `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY`.

Comment: These values mean that paths, **relative to sysroot**, should work as hints. It is strange that your path hint works for include directory but doesn't work for libraries. Have you tried *clean reconfiguration*? (Remove build directory an rerun CMake). If you don't provide any hint, does error message change? (Again, use clean reconfiguration for checking this).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Same thing. I tried removing the CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH and then it found OpenSSL, but for x86_64 instead of the target platform. The cross-compiled OpenSSL is `1.0.1f` and not `1.0.2g` apparently.

Answer (score 9):

In Linux, I didn't have any problem setting OpenSSL.

### In Windows, I solved as explained below.

Try removing `CMakeCache.txt` file and then do again. The cache Cmake is the main problem.

For instance, I did `cmake . -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=C:\openssl-1.0.2 -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\openssl-1.0.2\include -DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY=C:\openssl-1.0.2\crypto` and everything got solved. The logic is same.

[image]

Comment: I faced the same problem, and deleting the `CMakeCache.txt` file worked for me as well. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For MacOs I encounter the same error while installing ton'slite client (cmake ~/lite-client)

Solved as follows: I have open the "CMakeCache.txt" file in "liteclient-build" directory, find the line

```
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
```

and change it to with my openssl location

```
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```